# how to make a lighting effect using css/html/js

Tags: html, css, lighting

I am trying to make a lighting effect for a specific area in a webpage. I am wondering what technique I should use to make this effect like the following webpage.

So, is it possible to achieve this by using just css/html? If not, what else should I know to do this?

[image]

Comment: would it be an option to make this in some programm like photoshop and just use it as a background?

Comment: its possible if you have an png image of the light with transparent background , then using css and js you could position it , move it on top , and set opacity

Comment: I still do not understand how I can achieve this effect by using 2 background images as what people said in the following answers. I do not need the dynamic light. I just need the static light background. I dont know how to use photoshop, so that is why I just want to use css/html to do it. As the following people said, using a black background image with alpha transparency to overlay the original background image will make the lighting effect? How about the shape of lighting. How could I make the cylindrical lighting shape like the image above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to animate the light moving across the page horizontally you can start with two background images (one as the full "lit" image and one as the black shadow image with alpha transparency that lets the full lit image shine through).

Put the full lit image as the `background-image:` of the `<html>` element and the shadow image as the `background-image:` of the `<body>` tag.

You can then "animate" by changing the background-image-position of the shadow image. You could also add a cool Parallax (http://stephband.info/jparallax/) effect by moving the "full lit" image as you move the shadow one.

Comment: The way your described make sense. but I still have question about it. I need to use a black shadow image with alpha transparency to cover the full lit original background image. Then change the alpha transparency to show the lighting effect. is this what you mean? if so, then how could I make the cylindrical lighting shape like the image above? The black shadow image is rectangle and I can only show the rectangle shape of the light?

Comment: Hypothetically: In photoshop create a layer and fill it with a black background. Then "erase" the part you want to be transparent. Save as a transparent .png file. If you want to animate the light "coming on" just put another div on top of the "shadow" div and use a css3 transform (or jquery) to animate it's opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this could be done with CSS3/HTML5 as a 'light' effect as such - you might be able to achieve it however using gradients that are black at one end and opaque black at the other, overlaid on a fully 'lit' version of the photo.

I'm assuming you're trying to do it with CSS because the image being 'lit' is going to change dynamically?  If so, I'd create a transparent PNG in Illustrator and have your images display underneath it (easily done using CSS absolute positioning).

Comment: I'd recommend working on creating a 'dark' PNG that's transparent as opposed to trying to 'light up' a picture as that will just come out looking whiter (not lighter) depending on the image on which it is overlaid.

Answer (score 0):

I know of view people who have done with a jquery library. I am not sure it meets your needs, but you can have a look. Have a look at http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-illuminate/